# Load a file in MATLAB, where in each cell there is "garbage" value

Tags: matlab

My data is in the format:

```
Value1 junk:Value2 junk:Value3 ....
....
```

I'd like to get only the values. Note that the junk are actually indices (with offset 1) ranging from 1 to 256, and the first element in each row does not have junk value.

**Example:**

```
6 1:-1.000000 2:-1.000000 3:-1.000000 4:-1.000000 5:-1.000000 6:-1.000000 7:-1.000000 8:-0.631000 9:0.862000 10:-0.167000
1 1:-1.000000 2:-1.000000 3:-1.000000 4:-1.000000 5:-1.000000 6:-1.000000 7:-1.000000 8:0.510000 9:-0.213000 10:-1.000000
```

I'd like to get from the above the following as a matrix:

```
6 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -0.631000 0.862000 -0.167000
1 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 0.510000 -0.213000 -1.000000
```

when using `load(myFile)` I get only the junk (with exception of the first element in each row).

How should I parse it in MATLAB?

Comment: Wonder why the downvote. Is the question not clear? Didn't I say what I tried [load()] and why it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) and utilize the asterisk (`*`) to ignore certain fields. For instance:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt', 'r');                         %// Open the input file
A = textscan(fid, ['%f', repmat('%*[^:]:%f', 1, 10)]); %// Parse lines
fclose(fid);                                           %// Close the input file
A = [A{:}];                                            %// Convert into a matrix
```

Here `%*[^:]` matches the "junk" field (any sequence of characters until the first colon). The asterisk tells `textscan` to ignore it. Then a colon is matched, and then a floating-point number. This pattern is repeated 10 times.

Another possibility is to treat the colon as whitespace with:

```
A = textscan(fid, ['%f', repmat('%*s %f', 1, 10)], 'Whitespace', ' :\b\t');
```

thus achieving the same effect for the given example. This looks less elegant, IMHO.

Comment: The '10' here is just an example, I actually have 256 junk:Value in each line. but I get the point. What will it do for the first entry in each line? (i.e. the one without junk value)?

Comment: @amit Note that there's an additional `%f` concatenated to the 10×`junk:%f` pattern, so the first value is also parsed and stored in the output matrix `A`, just like you want. Try it!

Comment: Hi quick follow up question, if I don't know the number of columns in advance, (10 in the example) - what should I do?